# LinkControl not showing suggestions when used on admin page

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor

My goal is simple, I'd like to use the LinkControl element on an admin page rendered by my plugin. Using the LinkControl on the BlockEditor page is quite easy the issue is doing it without being inside the Edit/Save functions of a custom block.

These are the steps I did:

1. On the php of my custom admin page I included the scripts: `['wp-blocks', 'wp-block-editor', 'wp-element']`
2. I also included my script `admin.js` using the `wp_enqueue_scripts`
3. Inside main.js I have:

```
wp.element.render(
    wp.element.createElement( wp.blockEditor.__experimentalLinkControl,{
        onChange:function(value){console. Debug(value);},
        showSuggestions:true,
        value:{url:'test'}
    } ),
    document.getElementById( 'my_linkcontrol' )
);
```

The LinkControl shows but doesn't suggest any entries when you write something. I assume it has something to do with block editor settings: `__experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions`

**Update**:As explained on this [git issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/32087) LinkControl calls a function specified on the editor-block settings to fetch the suggestions (that's why `<LinkControl />` works on a custom block edit.js) :

```
import { __experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions as fetchLinkSuggestions } from '@wordpress/core-data';
initializeEditor( id, settings ) {
settings.__experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions = ( search, searchOptions )
=> fetchLinkSuggestions( search, searchOptions, settings );
```

This is called when intatiating the block-editor but I can't do that with my code. How can I specify editor settings if I'm not loading the editor, only `<LinkControl />`

[image]

Comment: the documentation for that component states its default behaviour doesn't do anything and you have to provide it yourself, and has a link to an example https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5c39cdb805c4a54ba4d30e5f8948aa2c2569985d/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control/README.md#L9 Can you expand your code snippet? Is this running on an event or hook?

Comment: This runs inside a script that is loaded on an admin form I implemented (admin.php?page=my_custom_form). When I'm enqueuing the scripts I first add the block-edtiro script. I saw the documentation but if I use <LinkControl /> but inside the edit.js of a custom block I implemented it shows the suggestion without any other prop.

Comment: This is done when initializing the editor but I'm outside the editor , I'm on an admin page: 
export function initializeEditor( id, settings ) {
 settings.__experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions = ( search, searchOptions ) =>
  fetchLinkSuggestions( search, searchOptions, settings );

Comment: can you edit that code into the question rather than a comment? Comments don't work for blocks of code, only inline `like this`

Comment: @TomJNowell done

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless using isolated block editor, [based on a reply from one of the Wordpress developers](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/32087#issuecomment-1253354100) which was really helpful.